# Java SIP client like present in android

Tags: java, servlets

My requirement is to do a SIP registration using java servlet  and then make an audio call. In android i have found simple way to do [Android Supporting SIP](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip#requirements) however i am not able use same android code in java since SIP manager class is present in android.net packages. What should i use for my users to do SIP registration in java servlet.

below is android code

```
if (sipManager == null) {
 sipManager = SipManager.newInstance(this);
}
SipProfile.Builder builder = null;
try {
 builder = new SipProfile.Builder("7001", "XXX.XXX.X.XXX");
 builder.setPassword("XXX");
 sipProfile = builder.build();
 Intent i = new Intent();
 i.setAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
 PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
 sipManager.open(sipProfile, pi, null);

 sipManager.setRegistrationListener(sipProfile.getUriString(), new SipRegistrationListener() {
  public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {

  }
  public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {

  }
  public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode,
   String errorMessage) {


  }
 });
} catch (ParseException pe) {
 pe.printStackTrace();

} catch (SipException se) {
 se.printStackTrace();

}
```

Comment: What do you mean using Java servlet? A servlet is server side, how will the client do the audio call from the server?

Comment: I have jsp page which makes ajax call to servlets

Comment: Yes, but how do you imagine this to actually work? If the servlet sends the signalling to initiate the call from the server, then what?

Comment: first thing is the SIP registration which taken care by jsp like user fill out thier client details and we have to do  SIP registration once it's done we can make a SIP VOIP. after all its a SIP based Communication for voice call. I am posting the android code in question as well.

Comment: Android is client based. It is running on the client's device, so it is straightforward. A servlet is running on a server on a different network.

Comment: yeah i need client based in java code only. since android SIP manager class is not available in java what should i use. Please see the code of andorid in question. this is how i am registering a Sip profile. How can i do in java or even in Javascript. I want to register a sip client

Comment: OK, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from your question how do you envisage this to work. Servlets are server side, so if SIP messages are initiated from the server but I suspect what you really want is to initiate a SIP session, followed by an Audio stream established with some real-time streaming protocol from the client.

There are Java APIs for SIP, and Sun / Oracle had a standard API for integrating with telecoms networks using SIP and IMS: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/introduction-jain-sip-090386.html
Not sure if they are still maintained.

However, I suspect that this is not what you really need. Maybe you should look at this client based WebRTC and SIP client:

http://www.doubango.org/sipml5/

Your JSP would serve this Javascript, which allows the user to initiate a SIP session and establish the Audio call.

From their documentation, it seems to be straightforward:

```
  SIPml.init(
     function(e){
         var stack =  new SIPml.Stack({realm: 'example.org', impi: 'bob', impu: 'sip:bob@example.org', password: 'mysecret',
                            events_listener: { events: 'started', listener: function(e){
                                        var callSession = stack.newSession('call-audiovideo', {
                                                video_local: document.getElementById('video-local'),
                                                video_remote: document.getElementById('video-remote'),
                                                audio_remote: document.getElementById('audio-remote')
                                            });
                                        callSession.call('alice');
                                    } 
                                }
                        });
                        stack.start();
                    }
            );
```

Comment: SIPml demo is throwing an error SIPml-api.js?svn=252:1 WebSocket connection to 'ws://ns313841.ovh.net:14060/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. is it a usable ? i am not able to register my SIP client to it in demo page

Comment: Well I don't know about its stability... feel free to look for other SIP clients, but what you need is a browser based solution so an HTML5 / Javascript solution. Are you sure that the host and port are reachable? The error seems to be pretty self explanatory that the host is not reachable on that port (or the port number is wrong, or some firewall is stopping it etc.) Connection refused is a socket error message, so nothing to do with stability of the library.

Comment: its not my server ip and ports

Comment: I think they are wrong or unreachable. I tried this to test if the host is listening on port 14060: `telnet ns313841.ovh.net 14060` and I got 
`Connecting To ns313841.ovh.net...Could not open connection to the host, on port 14060: Connect failed`. You can try it from your PC too to verify.

Comment: ns313841.ovh.net 14060 is not my server it's there . do i need to do some server side configuration ? I want just client so that it's get register and make a call. For testing purpose I have my sip domain name, user name and password which I am entering its gets authenticated but not making voice call to my another accoint

Comment: I have check other demos also they are also not working like jssip, sip js

Comment: @FerozSiddiqui You've got the wrong server or port. Where did you get those details from? That host is definitely not listening on the public internet on that port.

Comment: You can even verify here: https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/. Put the server and port, and you will see it is not reachable.

Comment: tsip_transport.js?svn=252:359 WebSocket connection to 'wss://ns313841.ovh.net:13062/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED this is js which is used in demo(IP here is not mine so i dont know what to do next ). I am not sure what to do with it. tsip_transport.js is provided by SIPml

Comment: @FerozSiddiqui not sure what you are expecting to magically happen. Neither port 14060 nor 13062 are listening. Test the ports from the site I gave you to check the ports are open, they are not even publicly listening. You can't expect the SIP client to connect to it if it is not listening on the internet.

Comment: i think they didnt mention how to configure websocket response. I have seen their documentation but not sure how to configure a websocket which is supposed to hosted on my servers. what response should i return once websocket is connected is not mentions